# Webform page wizard and submission data - no reference to which page the element was on

Tags: 8, webforms

I am creating a multi-page webform questionaire using the Page wizard.

I have also created a custom handler so I can manipulate the data from the form when completed.

My issue is that when using $webform_submission->getData in the method 'submitForm' in my webform handler class to gather the data, there is no reference to which page the element is from, the array simply contains the element key and value pair.

What would be a proper way of figuring out which page each element is from?

Comment: Maybe add a hidden field from the UI and then prepopulate it with the current URL using `hook_form_alter`?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this in the end was to use a method on the webform object called getPagesWithElements.

```
// Get webform object
$webform_obj = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('webform_id');
// Get page/element structure
$model = $this->getPagesWithElements($webform_obj);
```